# Why is Electricsheep on Debian not using the mplayer configuration for display settings?

Tags: mplayer, screensaver

I have set electricsheep for screensaver in Debian.
I want to run it in full screen, at 25 fps, but it runs at 23 fps with a very strange resolution.
Checking on `ps` it return this

```
ps -efww|grep mpla
user  2481  2479 28 21:58 ?        00:02:24 mplayer -really-quiet -cache 8192 -monitoraspect 1280:800 -fps 23 -vo vdpau -wid 0x1C0000A -nostop-xscreensaver -
user  2483  2481  0 21:58 ?        00:00:01 mplayer -really-quiet -cache 8192 -monitoraspect 1280:800 -fps 23 -vo vdpau -wid 0x1C0000A -nostop-xscreensaver -
```

This is the `.electricsheep/preferences.xml`  file:

```
<preferences
 nick=""
 url=""
 password=""
 cache="2000"
 nrepeats="2"
 frame_rate="23"
 play_evenly="1"
 uid="8253CA41C62618E5"
 zoom="1"
 video_driver="vdpau"
 no_animation="0"
 standalone="0"
 hide_errors="0"
 save_frames="0"
/>
```

This is my `mplayer` config

```
# Write your default config options here!
vo=vdpau
menu=yes
vf=screenshot
fullscreen=yes
softvol=yes
softvol-max=300
msgcolor=yes
aspect=16:9
tskeepbroken=true
use-filename-title=yes
```

Why, instead of running at fullscreen with 16:9 aspect as Slackware did, does it run with its own options?
I have solved the framerate problem, but it still runs at a strange resolution of 1280:800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution as workaround(it give strange results with some movie)
Editing .mplayer/config and add

```
panscan=1.0
```

The best would be to set this option only for electricsheep.